# Javascript reduce push individual sums + final sum

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having trouble fully understanding [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

I have this array:

```
const fooArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Which I'm trying to do is push the individual increment sums into a new array, for example:

```
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Here is my reduce function:

```
const barArray = [];
fooArray.reduce((previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex) => {
    barArray.push(previousValue)
    return previousValue + currentValue;
});
```

which works partly, `barArray` becomes

```
[1, 3, 6, 10]
```

Except you'll notice that `fooArray` is 5 in length and `barArray` is 4, it's missing the final sum, which should be 15. I know that `previousValue + currentValue` would sum it all up, but I just can't connect how to push that into the end of the array after all the incremental sums are added.

Any help is appreciated.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4u2fopyg/2/

Comment: It might be helpful to switch out the really huge numbers with something smaller. If `fooArray` were just `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, it might be easier to see what's going on. If `fooArray` were `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, then should `barArray` become `[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]`?

Comment: How about you start with `const barArray = [fooArray[0]];` or provide `0` as second parameter to `reduce`, and use `barArray.push(previousValue + currentValue)`?

Comment: To elaborate on the second option: `const barArray = []; fooArray.reduce((p, c) => { barArray.push(p + c); return p + c; }, 0);` - providing an initial value for `reduce` is often a good idea anyways.

Comment: @Helium_1s2 that is correct, yes. I've added a jsfiddle with the simplified version

Comment: It's not super essential -- it just makes it *much* easier to quickly see what's going on, and hence debug it.

Comment: @ASDFGerte setting const barArray = [fooArray[0]] just makes the function return the first sum twice (e.g. [1, 1, 3, 6, 10]), providing 0 as the second parameter just makes the function return 0 as the first thing in BarArray

Comment: Note that the sentence is meant as "do ((... XOR ...) AND ...)", as in you have to change the code of the function given to `reduce` either way.

Comment: This is happening because you aren't declaring the initial value of the reduce. Declare the initial value (after the arrow function) to `[]` and it should fix your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about this a bit more... since you want an array the same length as the original, I feel like a *map* operation may be more appropriate.

You can make use of `Array.prototype.map` *thisArg* to keep track of the running total

```js
const fooArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const barArray = fooArray.map(function(n) { // Note: not an arrow function
  return this.last += n
}, {last: 0}) // the "this" arg

console.info(barArray)
```

---

**Original answer here**

One option is to initialise the reduce *carry* array argument to the first `fooArray` element then perform the reduce on the rest of the elements, adding to the last element value as you go

For example

```js
const fooArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const barArray = fooArray.slice(1).reduce((previousValue, currentValue, index) => {
  previousValue.push(previousValue[index] + currentValue)
  return previousValue
}, [fooArray[0]]);

console.info(barArray)
```

This ensures that within the reducer callback, there is always a previous value set (ie `previousValue[index]`) to add on to.

Note that `.slice(1)` creates a shallow copy of the original array (minus the first element) which may or may not be of some concern.

---

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173440/discussion-between-phil-and-derek).

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate the cumulative sum and return it at each step after pushing it to `barArray`, while making sure to pass `0` as the `initialValue` to `.reduce()`:

```js
const fooArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const barArray = [];
const total = fooArray.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
  const sum = previousValue + currentValue;
  barArray.push(sum);
  return sum;
}, 0);

console.log('barArray:', barArray.join(), 'total:', total);
```

Alternatively you can pass a tuplet as the accumulator, which might be a preferred style for some:

```js
const fooArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const [barArray, total] = fooArray.reduce(([barArray, previousValue], currentValue) => {
  const sum = previousValue + currentValue;
  barArray.push(sum);
  return [barArray, sum];
}, [[], 0]);

console.log('barArray:', barArray.join(), 'total:', total);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var fooArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var result = fooArray.reduce(function(result,incr,index){ result.push((result[index-1] || 0) + incr); return result }, [] ); //increment by index[0] or index -1 and return result by adding last element value. 
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Question: _I'm having trouble fully understanding `Array.reduce`_ Answer: _Use reduce to build the `answer` directly._ That's not an explanation.

Comment: @Derek bro did not get you what you are trying to tell :-)